# Quotient rule for the Jacobian

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives

Is there an analog to the quotient rule that can be applied to the calculation of the Jacobian?

Example: Can the jacobian of a quotient of two functions be decomposed into some series of linear combinations? (Both functions take the same parameters in this instance).

${\bf{J}}\left[\frac{f(x,y,z)}{g(x,y,z)}\right] = {\bf{A}}_f\left(x,y,z\right){\bf{B}}_g\left(x,y,z\right)$

Where ${\bf{A}}_f$ is a function of the jacobian of ${f}$ and ${\bf{B}}_g$ is a function of the jacobian of g.

EDIT: I should note that ${\frac{f}g}$ is vector function of the triplet x,y,z.

Comment: Are $f$ and $g$ scalar functions? If yes, we are talking about the gradient not the Jacobian. If f and g a vector valued, how you want to perform division??

Comment: Element-wise division of the vectors.